# Center a div and append a right menu to that div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I need to center a main div and append a fixed menu to the right of that item. I need the main div to stay in the center and the right menu to "fix" to the centered div.

Currently, I'm using `flex` to center the div, but this is resulting in both items centering (meaning the main div is not truly in the center).

**This is the desired layout:**

[image: desired result]

**Current layout:**

[image: current layout]

The code appears as below (I'm using React with styled components):

**Container:**

```
const DivContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 60;
  width: 100%;
`;
```

**Main Div:**

```
const MainDiv = styled.div`
  width: 300px;
  padding: 35px 15px;
`;
```

**Menu div:**

```
const MenuDiv = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 85px;
  order: 10;
`;
```

This is rendered as the below:

```
<DivContainer>
  <MainDiv />
  <MenuDiv />
</DivContainer>
```

Comment: One hackish way to do this would be to make the menu div absolute within the relative parent. The set it's left margin to the width of the parent. Otherwise, flex is not the right solution for the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the sidebar inside the container and push it out with a negative margin right

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.center {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: 2px solid magenta;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* important */
  float: right;
  margin-right: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="center">
    content
    <div class="sidebar">
      sidebar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*ps: for the snippet click full page*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It feels hacky (and causes issues when the screen is resized), but this ended up working with the aid of a few media queries.

Answer (score 1):

You could just wrap it in a zero width div, with overflow visible:

```css
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    border: solid 3px green;
    justify-content: center;
}

#main {
    border: solid 2px orange;
    width: 50%;
}

#no-width {
    width: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}

#menu {
    width: 100px;
    border: solid red 2px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main">
        Centered
    </div>
    <div id="no-width">
        <div id="menu">
            "Zero" width div, so doesn't affect centering
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in another div with same width as main div and set min-width for its child

```css
.wrapper {
      display: flex;
      width: 300px;
    }
    .container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .main {
      width: 300px;
      min-width: 300px;
      min-height: 200px;
      background-color: aquamarine;
    }

    .menu {
      width: 80px;
      min-width: 80px;
      min-height: 200px;
      background-color: cadetblue;
      position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="menu"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```